# Class function issue. C++

Tags: c++

I'm presently writing code to simulate collisions of ideal gasses. The collision in this case is elastic (no lose of energy). 
I have already written code to calculate all I need, including the time and position at which they meet. In my class function I define:

`Particle.cpp`

```
    void Particle::collideParticles(Particle particle){

    double tCollision;

    tCollision=timeToCollision(particle);


    if(tCollision >= 0 && (!testFloat(tCollision,FLT_MAX, 0.1))){

        move(tCollision);
        particle.move(tCollision);

        Vector r2=particle.getPosition();
        Vector r1=p;
        Vector r0=r2-r1;
        Vector n=r0.unit();
        Vector v1=n;
        Vector v2=n;

        v1.Scale(v.dot(n));
        v2.Scale(particle.getVelocity().dot(n));

        Vector deltaV=v2-v1;

        setVelocity(v+deltaV);
        particle.setVelocity(particle.getVelocity()-deltaV);

    }

}
```

My apologies for confusing terminology.

- `Vector` refers to a class with components x, y, z.
- `Scale`, scales a Vector (x,y,z)
- `Unit` takes a unit vector.
- `timeToCollision` is an earlier class function that calculates and returns the time for two particles to collide.
- `FLT_MAX` is a value from `<cfloat>` doesnt play a role in my problem as the example is within the 0 and FLT_MAX. List item

By use of couting values I've established this code works; however, when I call this function in

`Main.cpp`

```
    Vector p1p(0,0,0);
    Vector p1v(1,0,0);
    Vector p2p(5,0,0);
    Vector p2v(0,0,0);
    Particle p1(1, p1p, p1v);
    Particle p2(1, p2p, p2v);

    cout << "Velocity of p1 before collide should be 1 on X, value is: " << p11.getVelocity().GetX() << endl;
    cout << "Velocity of p2 before collide should be 0 on X, value is: " << p2.getVelocity().GetX() << endl;

    p1.collideParticles(p2);

    cout << "Velocity of p1 should be 0 on X, value is: " << p11.getVelocity().GetX() << endl;
    cout << "Velocity of p2 should be 1 on X, value is: " << p2.getVelocity().GetX() << endl;
```

I get that the velocity in terms of x of particle 1 to begin to be 1, to end is 0, which is correct. Though it gives me that velocity in terms of x of particle 2 to be 0 to start and 0 again after collision.

I feel this is probably a simple mistake I've made or something I've forgotten and I have just stressed myself to the point I can't spot it. Any help greatly appreciated. Please do ask for anything to be clarified or explained further.

Dan.

Comment: Present your [mcve]​​​​​​​​​

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the particle as reference, now you are just passing a copy of the particle object and when the function ends it is destroyed. Change the function definition from:

```cpp
void Particle::collideParticles(Particle particle){

}
```

to

```
void Particle::collideParticles(Particle &particle){
}
```

Comment: That's exactly it, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if that fixes your problem, but the way you designed your method `collideParticles(Particle particle)` you are not manipulating the velocity of `Particle p2`, but the velocity of a copy of that object. You can try to change the method to `collideParticles(Particle& particle)`. By using a reference `Particle&` you can actually change the object `p2`.